# Querying REST API with Cursor Pagination from Server with Apollo-Server-Express

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, apollo-client, apollo-server

Using Apollo-Server-Express, I want to wrap a REST API with GraphQL. I'm starting with the free to use SWAPI (Star Wars API). I can't find anything about server side fetching with cursor paging using apollo-server-express. The only thing that I found that could be a possibility since it's for the Apollo Client is fetchMore. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here's my code:

schema.js

```
// Imports: GraphQL
import { makeExecutableSchema } from 'graphql-tools';

// Imports: GraphQL TypeDefs & Resolvers
import TYPEDEFS from './types.js';
import RESOLVERS from './resolvers.js';


// GraphQL: Schema
const SCHEMA = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs: TYPEDEFS,
  resolvers: RESOLVERS
});

export default SCHEMA;
```

types.js

```
const TYPEDEFS = `
    type Query {
    getFilm(id: ID): Film
    getAllFilms: [Film]
}

type Film {
    title: String!
    episode_id: Int!
    opening_crawl: String
    director: String
    producer: String
    release_date: String
    characters: [Person]
    planets: [Planet]
    starships: [Starship]
    vehicles: [Vehicle]
    species: [Species]
    created: String
    edited: String
    url: String
    }
}`

export default TYPEDEFS;
```

resolvers.js

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';


const RESOLVERS = {
    Query: {
        // Search for a Film by ID
        getFilm: async (parent, args) => {
            const response = await
            fetch(`https://swapi.co/api/films/${args.id}`);
            return response.json();
        },
        getAllFilms: async (parent, args) => {
            const response = await
            fetch(`https://swapi.co/api/films/`);
            return response.json();
        }
    }
};

export default RESOLVERS;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe `apollo-server` does not provide cursor pagination out of the box.

You can either implement it yourself. Or you can use(or get inspired) by the one that [Relay](https://facebook.github.io/relay/graphql/connections.htm) uses.

And according to [Apollo client](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/features/pagination.html#relay-cursors) if you use Relay style cursor pagination the client has support for it.